# Extra X-Frame-Options header

Tags: x-frameoption

I have a clean version Sitecore 9.3 including the SXA module installed using the Sitecore Install Assistant.

In Chrome when I open the Content Editor for the home page, the Rich Text field display a 'refused to connect' error.

The browser console displays the following error:

> Refused to display https://XXX/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich%20Text%20Editor/EditorWindow.aspx' in a w>frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN  >ALLOW-FROM 'https://youtube/com''). Falling back to 'deny'.

Looking at the response there are two X-Frame-Option headers:

- X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN  ALLOW-FROM 'https://youtube/com'

I know the first header is added by the SitecoreXFrameOptionsHeaderModule  module.

But where does the second header come from and how can it be removed?

Answer (score 1):

we ran into similar problem, and in our case, the "second" x-frame-options header comes from the Sitecore Forms module, because there is a form on the page and it seems that forms module adds this header by default

Comment: Hi @gmaklari,
How did you remove second x-frame-options header . As same happening for me and my page contains the sitecore forms

Comment: Hi @Singh, in our case we did not want to remove it globally, only on special pages, so we implemented it via simple controller action, where we used the following header modifier:
`Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");`
You can create for example a separated rendering for this with name "RemoveXFrameOptions" add it to the layout details only on the required page items.

Comment: Thanks @gmaklari.